# How to insert text into the cursor position in a powepoint shape's TextRange

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop, cursor-position

I have a power point text box and some text in it. When the user selects the text to edit I need to add some text to the cursor point.

As an example:

If the current text is "ABCEFG" and the user puts a cursor point like "ABC|EFG" I need to edit the text as "ABCDEFG".

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
    .InsertAfter ("D")
End With
```

Comment: ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange returns the currently selected text range (which might include no text if you've just clicked within a textbox).  .InsertAfter inserts the specified characters(s) after the current text range.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the following link.
Think it will be helpful for your cause.

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?32289-Alternative-way-to-determine-current-cursor-position-in-text-box

Thanks,